# How can I copy custom properties in blender

Tags: python, properties, custom-properties

Copy form active object to another,
or to multiple objects.

Thank u!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

via the UI.

Enable the built-in addon. In Edit > Preferences > Addons, enable 'Interface: Copy Attributes Menu' to enable it.

In the 3D view, select the *to* object, then shift-select the *from* object.  then ctrl-C will give you a popup where the last item is what you want:

[image]

Comment: I think that's from a built-in addon which isn't enabled by default. Search 'Copy' under Edit > Preferences > Addons and enable 'Interface: Copy Attributes Menu' to enable it.

Comment: thank u, i found it in the latest vertion

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

#### Copy custom properties to selected objects from active object

```
import bpy

act = bpy.context.object
act_items = act.items()
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj == act: continue
    for k, e in act_items:
        obj[k] = e
```